# how to open default email client(like outlook,windows live message,lotus) by java with attachments?

Tags: java, email, email-client, jacob

Actually, I have tried

```
                 Desktop.mail(URI uri)
```

but this can't support for the attachment.

Also I tried jacob which use ActiveXComponent to support. This looks nice in Outlook.

```
                 ActiveXComponent oOutlook =   ActiveXComponentHelper.newActiveXComp("Outlook.Application");
                 Dispatch mail = Dispatch.invoke(oOutlook.getObject(), "CreateItem", Dispatch.Get, new Object[] { "0" }, new int[0])
                                 .toDispatch();
                 Dispatch.put(mail, "HTMLBody", htmlText);
                 Dispatch attachmentsObj = Dispatch.get(mail, "Attachments").toDispatch();
```

Is this support for Windows Live Message and Lotus?And what is the progId for them?

Or there is some other to do this better?

Thanks in advance for your help.